# Disable X-Frame-Options header in Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, headers

I have a site that, by necessity, needs to load into an iFrame on another site.
Part of the site is a Channel Form however this page won't load into the iFrame because the X-Frame-Options header is being set. I see the addition of this header was an update in 2.5.

Does anyone know how I can stop this header from being set?  I don't think I have any option other than to modify the Core but I can't find where it's being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found where the header is being set...

It's within system/expressionengine/libraries/Cp.php:

```
73          // Make sure all requests to iframe the CP are denied
74:         ee()->output->set_header('X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin');
```